# Object does not exist at location

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm using firebase storage for my Android app.

Intermittently I'm seeing end-user reports for non fatal exceptions in Firebase Crash reporting:

```
Exception com.google.firebase.storage.StorageException: Object does not exist at location. 
com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.run (FileDownloadTask.java) 
com.google.firebase.storage.zzr.run (zzr.java) 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```

The object exists at the specified location. And for most of the end-users we are not seeing this issue. But a few users are reporting this issue.

I'm using the following code to download file:

```
FirebaseStorage mStoragePath;
mStoragePath = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
mStoragePath.setMaxDownloadRetryTimeMillis(RETRY_MS);
mStoragePath.setMaxOperationRetryTimeMillis(RETRY_MS);
mStoragePath.setMaxUploadRetryTimeMillis(RETRY_MS);

StorageReference storageRef = mStoragePath.getReference();
StorageReference pathReference = storageRef.child("myDB" + inPath);
FileDownloadTask downloadTask = pathReference.getFile(outFile);
downloadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
            if(exception instanceof StorageException) {
                // Getting exception here!
            }
        }
    });
```

Is this a known issue in Firebase 11.6.0?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [StorageException has occurred. Object does not exist at location. Storage FireBase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42982147/storageexception-has-occurred-object-does-not-exist-at-location-storage-fireba)