# StorageException has occurred.Object does not exist at location.Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404 in android studio logcat

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

Here is my logcat:

> 2018-11-04 08:54:03.257 20512-20582/com.example.nabil.logindemo
>   E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
>       Object does not exist at location.
>        Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404 2018-11-04 08:54:03.268 20512-20582/com.example.nabil.logindemo E/StorageException: { 
>   "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get
>   object"  }}
>       java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object"  }}
>           at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:455)
>           at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:435)
>           at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:426)
>           at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:280)
>           at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:294)
>           at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:65)
>           at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:57)
>           at com.google.firebase.storage.GetDownloadUrlTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:71)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784) 2018-11-04 08:54:03.945 20512-20512/com.example.nabil.logindemo E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.nabil.logindemo, PID: 20512
>       android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xfffffffd
>           at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:410)
>           at android.content.res.HwResources.getText(HwResources.java:465)
>           at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:328)
>           at com.example.nabil.logindemo.ProfileActivity$2.onCancelled(ProfileActivity.java:65)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireCancelEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:80)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.CancelEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:40)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:55)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
>   2018-11-04 08:54:03.959 731-2760/? E/iMonitor: FaultDetect:
>   DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return. 2018-11-04 08:54:03.962 731-2760/? E/iMonitor:
>   FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return. 2018-11-04 08:54:03.966
>   1248-3184/? E/ReportTools: This is not beta user build 2018-11-04
>   08:54:03.970 731-2760/? E/iMonitor: FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF
>   return. 2018-11-04 08:54:03.970 731-2760/? E/iMonitor: FaultDetect:
>   DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return. 2018-11-04 08:54:03.970 731-2760/? E/iMonitor:
>   FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return. 2018-11-04 08:54:03.970
>   731-2760/? E/iMonitor: FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return. 2018-11-04
>   08:54:04.057 1859-1884/? E/HsmCoreServiceImpl: onTransact in code is:
>   103

Here is my Java code.

**ProfileActivity.Java:**

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView profilename,emailid,age;
private ImageView imageprofile;
private Button btnedit;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
private FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage;
private StorageReference storageReference;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
    profilename=findViewById(R.id.profilename);
    emailid=findViewById(R.id.emailid);
    age=findViewById(R.id.age);
    imageprofile=findViewById(R.id.imageprofile);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    firebaseStorage=FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    storageReference=firebaseStorage.getReference();
    storageReference.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Images/Profile Pic").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            Picasso.get().load(uri).into(imageprofile);
        }
    });
    DatabaseReference databaseReference=firebaseDatabase.getReference(firebaseAuth.getUid());
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            DatabaseValues databaseValues=dataSnapshot.getValue(DatabaseValues.class);
            profilename.setText("Name: "+ databaseValues.getProfile_name());
            emailid.setText("Email: "+ databaseValues.getProfile_username());
            age.setText("Age: "+ databaseValues.getProfile_age());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this,databaseError.getCode(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

**DatabaseValues.Java:**

```
public class DatabaseValues {
private String profile_name;
private String profile_username;
private String profile_age;

public DatabaseValues(){

}

public DatabaseValues(String profile_name, String profile_username, String profile_age) {
    this.profile_name = profile_name;
    this.profile_username = profile_username;
    this.profile_age = profile_age;
}

public String getProfile_name() {
    return profile_name;
}

public void setProfile_name(String profile_name) {
    this.profile_name = profile_name;
}

public String getProfile_username() {
    return profile_username;
}

public void setProfile_username(String profile_username) {
    this.profile_username = profile_username;
}

public String getProfile_age() {
    return profile_age;
}

public void setProfile_age(String profile_age) {
    this.profile_age = profile_age;
}
}
```

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: check at my answer I could solve it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42982147/storageexception-has-occurred-object-does-not-exist-at-location-storage-fireba/62419637#62419637

Answer (score 0):

That error means that your reference to the file in your Firebase Storage is not set correctly.

Check this line, the path of that image `/Profile Pic` does not exists in your storage.

You will need to edit your reference in order to get it to work

```
storageReference.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Images/Profile Pic")...
```